# C# .net-core Web API Serilog: log files to different folders based on property (i.e. controller name)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

Our client wants log files stored in separate folders based on the controller.  For example, all logs that hit the Shipping controller would be stored in C:\logs\shipping\ while those that hit the orders controller would be in c:\logs\orders and so on.  Below is my ConfigureLoggingServices method.  I'm using Serilog and writing to a file and to Seq.  I'm using middleware to capture the client user and session ID (stored in the request header) and pushing these values to the log entry with LogContext.PushProperty().  I somehow need to inject the name of the controller into the path of the log file.  Is this possible?  Thanks

```
private void ConfigureLoggingServices()
{
    var appName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:AppName", string.Empty);
    var SeqURL = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:SeqURL", string.Empty);
    var pool = Environment.UserName;

    //string logFile = "C:\\Logs\\" + {Controller} + "\\lis_api.log";
    string logFile = "C:\\Logs\\lis_api.log";
    const string customTemplate = "[{LIS_User} {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3} {SessionID}] {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";

    var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", appName)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", $"{name.Version}")
        .Enrich.WithProperty("AppPool", pool)
        .Destructure.ByTransforming<User>(x => new { x.ID, x.Name, x.Controller })

       // File Sink - Async
       .WriteTo.Async(a => a.
           File(string.Format(string.Format(logFile)),
           rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
           outputTemplate: customTemplate,
           fileSizeLimitBytes: 40000000,
           shared: true,
           retainedFileCountLimit: 50,
           rollOnFileSizeLimit: true))                  

        .WriteTo.Seq(SeqURL)

        .CreateLogger();

    LoggerFactory = CreateLoggerFactory();
}
```

Comment: Serilog.Sinks.Map

Comment: Looks like @RubenBartelink 's suggestion above is right on point and a very clean way to implement what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible to get a code sample with what I provided above that illustrates how to do this with Serilog.Sinks.Map?

Comment: Added below; hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
.WriteTo.Map(
    "Controller",
    "(None)",
    (ctrl, wt) => wt.File($"C:\\Logs\\{ctrl}\\lis_api.log"))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Couple of questions: 1) would this be added right after the WriteTo.Async section in the code I shared above? and 2) will it use the settings (i.e. outputTemplate, rollingInterval, etc) I specified by default?